# Pre-Loading, Prepopulating, Imprting data to existing CoreData store (SQLite)

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, core-data, import

I am in front of following problem:
I have a CoreData based IPhone app, which I already have prepopulated by adding a sqlite-db to the resources folder and copy it to the documents folder if not already there.
BUT: When I have to update the app and added a new SQLite db and the user already has a populated db in his document folder, how can I import the new data of the entity-tables into the existing db in the users document folder?

I found several threads about how to populate a db when the users-db is not already existing. I also found a lot about migrating, but that only changes the datastructure, but do not import new data from my db which I added to the resources folder.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Philipp

Answer (score 0):

The framework used to migrate the sqlite schema can also be used to load/migrate data during an app upgrade.  I believe you'd need to use NSMigrationManager to manage the migration and to load additional data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I use the migration, where do you place the populated store? Do you place it also inside the resources folder, but instead of copying it into the document folder, use the migration?

Comment: I would keep in in a plist file or some easily read text resource in the bundle.  Then during migration read the resource and populate the new schema using that data.